# How to get notification from redis if a key changes as part of 'restore' operation

Tags: python, redis

I have a python code listening for events from redis for 'testKey'.

```
# cat listen.py
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
p = r.pubsub()
p.psubscribe('__keyspace@0__:'+'testKey')

for item in p.listen():
    print(item)


# python listen.py
{'type': 'psubscribe', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'__keyspace@0__:testKey', 'data': 1}
```

I get notification if key is modified as part of 'del' or 'set' operation.
e.g:

```
# redis-cli -n 0 del testKey


{'type': 'pmessage', 'pattern': b'__keyspace@0__:testKey', 'channel': b'__keyspace@0__:testKey', 'data': b'del'}
```

But if key changes as part of 'restore' operation, there is no event generated.
e.g:

```
# redis-cli -n 2 --raw dump testKey | head -c-1  > file
# cat file | redis-cli -n 0 -x restore testKey 0
```

With above operation, my python code does not print anything.

If I check with 'redis-cli monitor', I can see this event:

```
# redis-cli  monitor
OK
1583920985.754163 [0 127.0.0.1:32770] "restore" "testKey" "0" "\x00\x06Value2\t\x00\x06\xa7L\xda\xd1Uq\r"
```

Is there a way to get notified on restore event for a key through python redis APIs?

Comment: Currently no, but thanks to your find I hope it will be a part of the upcoming v6 at the very least: https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/6976

Comment: @itamar-haber Thank you!